# docker: cannot map two container ports to one host port

Tags: python, docker, flask, dockerfile, pm2

app.json for pm2 (src/app.py is Flask app):

```
{
    "apps": [
    {
      "exec_mode": "fork",
      "script": "src/app.py",
      "args": ["-p", "8080"]
    },
    {
      "exec_mode": "fork",
      "script": "src/app.py",
      "args": ["-p", "8081"]
    }
  ]
}
~
```

Dockerfile:

```
EXPOSE 8080 8081
CMD ["pm2", "start", "app.json"]
```

Error when running docker:

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 -p 8080:8081 oct20
docker: Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint high_fermi (xxxxxxxxxxx): Bind for 0.0.0.0:8080 failed: port is already allocated.
```

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Yes you can t allocate a port twice

Comment: @user2915097 how to map two containers port to one host port? Is it possible?

Comment: You may want to look at HAProxy or some other load balancing solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't have two things listening on one port in the host - whether they're separate ports in one container, or two Docker containers, or two other apps. It's not a Docker limitation, it's part of the OS networking stack.

Where would the host send a request to port 8080 if you could do that in this case? To port 8080 in the container, or port 8081, or multicast it to both?

Comment: I would like to split the traffic to the two app(s) (8080, 8081). Maybe a load balancer can help me.

Comment: Yes, I would look at three containers - one for each app, and [and use Nginx as a load balancer](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/load_balancing.html). External traffic comes into Nginx, app containers don't need to expose any ports - the Nginx container can access container ports on the same Docker network.